# "I just jump in"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, usage

What does it mean "I just jump in" in the second sentence?

[image]

Am I right if I think about it accordingly to the Cambridge dictionary's definition: "to suddenly become involved in a situation or discussion"?

It seems quite appropriate in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what it means. The speaker found the courage to volunteer a remark without having been prompted to do so.

Answer (score 1):

*Jumping in* is basically committing to doing something - once you jump, you can't stop! You're on your way to whatever it is you jumped into. So the writer is saying they get involved without hesitating and slowly working up to it - they jump straight in.

You might also hear *dive in* (like diving into water, that's a confident jump!) or *throw yourself into something* which has more of a sense of bravery, not really wanting to do something so you force yourself into it.

There's also *take the plunge* which is another diving metaphor, but I think that tends to be used for doing new things, taking risks, having new experiences and overcoming fears for the first time. Also *look before you leap*, which basically means you should make sure of what you're jumping into before you do it! Being prepared and informed before you commit to something, basically.